# "Importing Custom Frameworks into a Playground" no such module

Tags: xcode6, xcode7

I am trying to use an external framework in Playground(import Alamofire)

I have followed [this](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/recipes/Playground_Help/Chapters/ImportFramework.html) but I keep getting "No such module 'Alamofire'.

Is this a bug in Xcode as I can see many people is struggling with this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Problem solved: The Playground file setting(in the file inspector), was set to OS X in a iOS project.